# "if" condition with "and" operator

Tags: python

When I run this code, it is fine and everything works as intended.

```py
while True:
    try:
        check_point_data = (str(input('Yes/No : ')))
        if check_point_data == 'Yes':
            print('Ok')
            break
        elif check_point_data == 'yes':
            print('Ok')
            break
        elif check_point_data == 'No':
            print('Try again later.')
            break
        elif check_point_data == 'no':
            print('Try again later.')
            break
        else:
            print('Only Yes or No is accepted.')
            continue
    except ValueError:
        break
```

but when I changed like following:

```py
while True:
    try:
        check_point_data = (str(input('Yes/No : ')))
        if check_point_data == 'Yes' and check_point_data == 'yes':
            print('Ok')
            break
        elif check_point_data == 'No' and check_point_data == 'no':
            print('Try again later.')
            break
        else:
            print('Only Yes or No is accepted.')
            continue
    except ValueError:
        break
```

It stopped working. Whatever I input, it printed out 'Only Yes or No is accepted.' message.

Can somebody explain to me where it went wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `and` with `or`. `check_point_data == 'Yes' and check_point_data == 'yes'` is never true.

Comment: Equality is transitive, so if that condition could be true, it would imply `'Yes' == 'yes'`.

Comment: Or just use `check_point_data.lower() == "yes"`...

Comment: If you want to account for other possibilities, something like: `if check_point_data.lower() in ('yes', 'y', 'ok', 'yep'):` would be a pattern to follow~

Answer (score 1):

This is because, in your modified code, you are checking if the `check_point_data` is both `Yes` and `yes` which cannot be possible. You have to check if `check_point_data` is either `Yes` or `yes`. Hence, the correct operator to use is `or` and not `and`

```py
if check_point_data == 'Yes' or check_point_data == 'yes':
    print('Ok')
    break
elif check_point_data == 'No' or check_point_data == 'no':
    print('Try again later.')
    break
```

---

Instead of checking whether it matches the cases `Yes` or `yes` or `YES` etc., directly use this: (Credits: **@Tyler V**)

```py
if check_point_data.lower() == "yes":
    // code
```